# BlueZ with Ubuntu Set-up

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to setup [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/download/) in Ubuntu 14.04 with the end goal of connecting my mobile phone to my computer. The website does not have many details of how to install it, and I do not have much experience with things like this, so I was wondering what steps I should take to do. And after it is installed, how do I run it? Thank you!

Comment: What will you do with the phone? And do you want to do it through some Desktop Environment, do you want some non-DE GUI tool, or do you prefer commandline utilities? BlueZ is mostly a library (nowadays a DBUS-based service) other applications rely on to use bluetooth, you will probably need additional tools to do something with the bluetooth link.

Answer (score 0):

Please use your package manager to reinstall the following plackages:

```
blueman, bluez-utils, bluez, bluetooth
```

Add this to startup if you want bluez to start on boot:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

EDIT

try this:

```
aptitude install bluez-utils blueman
```

if that doesn't work, install the following package:

```
obex-data-server
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When saying "sudo apt-get install blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth" I got an error saying "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming... blueman : Depends: obex-data-server (>= 0.4.3) but it is not going to be installed... E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." Do you know why this is? Thanks!

Comment: @egmarkel edited the initial response to provide more information.